# Animation nodes remove duplicate elements from list

Tags: animation-nodes

How can you remove duplicated items from a list of vectors, leaving only one of each item?

Comment: Try *List* -> *List Boolean Operations*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this expression: `[i for n, i in enumerate(x) if i not in x[:n]]`

[image]